# How to continue on my work, which is in Flash CS 5.5?

Tags: animation, adobe-flash, animate

After googling and learning (and much frustration) that Adobe canceled the Flash Prfessional Animation tools especially the CS5.5 version in which I still work, my issue is the following: (Leaving aside the rendering qulaity and solutions), I use the CS 5.5 for my animations since I have my animation heroes (4 months of full time work of finished symbols, turns, tweens movieclips, movements etc...) in that tool.

On my older computer I used to have the CS5.5, but for reasons of stories too long for this post, I now only have a laptop with Windows 10 and I would like to install one of the Adobe tools in which I cold work on my animations (but transfer them first succesfully). I see a posssibility in installing Animate on my laptop, but I dont know if it will open my old CS5.5 work. If I install the CS5.5 than there are the rendering issues... (Even if only the graphics without the movements survive in a newer tool, would be survivable for me...) I'm a little lost.

I would sincerely be grateful for your help.

Comment: Create a virtual machine of your old computer? But yeah this happens. Bigger companies have people on roster just to refresh old files to newer versions as they go. But yeah Flash as a ecosystem is gone forever quite some years back.

Comment: One possibility is to simply keep an older machine running with the software you need. It can often be cheaper to maintain an older system than put in hours of work learning new tools and migrating old files. Even a carpenter keeps that old hand-powered jigsaw around in case the new fangled electric saw isn't right for the job. (and.. then.. there's the Adobe CC change which **locks you out** of your **own copyrighted files** if you stop paying their subscription fees.)

Comment: Do you have plans to migrate this work out from Flash, I hope? Flash is completely dead & gone, forcibly removed from Windows computers, time-bombed by Apple and Adobe & no longer available. See [Super User - Use Flash Player after 12 Jan 2021](https://superuser.com/q/1616866/347380)

Comment: Try Animate and see how it goes. https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/how-to/convert-flash-ads-to-html5.html

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help! I am very grateful! joojaa, Scott, Tetsujin, Zach Saucier - you are all good people for helping!!!!! I will navigate through the input of your help from here on... Warm regards!